# USB 3.0 backward compatible external HDD in VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, external-hard-drive, osx-mavericks, xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 14.04 32-bit installed as a guest in VirtualBox 4.3.12, hosted on a MacBook Air running Mavericks. I can acccess two external USB non-NTFS drives in Xubuntu after ejecting them when Mavericks auto-mounts them.

However, I am not able to access a third external HDD (formated as NTFS). As this drive is "USB 3.0 compatible with USB 2.0", I expected that it would be accessible to the guest operating system in the same way as the other two drives. Xubuntu does not even detect the presence of the drive, as it does not appear under `/dev`.  `dmesg` reports "unable to enumerate usb on port1".

If this drive is compatible with USB 2.0, how can I access it in the guest operating system?

Notes

1. I have installed the VirtualBox guest additions.
2. I know that Mavericks can only read NTFS, but this is not relevant,
   as the drive is ejected in Mavericks in order to be accessible to
   the guest operating system.
3. I know the VirtualBox does not support USB 3.0.
4. Xubuntu does have the `ntfs-3g` package installed, but this is not
   relevant as the drive is not detected.

Comment: Happened to me today. My WD hard disk not recognised in Ubuntu 14.04 running inside Virtualbox on Macbook Pro host. I think because all USB port on MacBook Pro is USB 3.0, the disk connected to host in 3.0 mode. When Virtualbox try to mount that USB device, it's still on 3.0 mode and Virtualbox still not support this.

Comment: as a workaround I could connect a USB3 harddisk via a USB2 hub. Of course I will not get USB3 speeds but at least I can use the disk from Virtualbox (the read/write speed of the magnetic harddisk itself must be much below the maximum USB3 speed anyway)